# Problems with readdir() and fgets

Tags: c, loops, fgets, readdir

I'm writing a code where I can be given a directory of .txt files, and specific strings that appear throughout each file, and do some simple comparisons. code chunk will be posted below.

So, My task:Open directory>open file>compare strings>open next file(repeat)
Until I run out of files.

What is wrong:My code currently prints the first file name( full path name) infinitely until it crashes, nothing is printed to `fp1`. It is supposed to only print the file name once, but it never gets past that first file, where, obviously, I would like it to go through all the files in the directory.

I'm sorry that I'm fairly new to **C** so I might be unclear as to how these functions actually operate.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I want to see if I understand correctly.

```
while ((in_file = readdir(FD))!= NULL){
```

Should basically traverse through a directory and "look" the name of each file. 
I then do some very inefficient work around, which you will probably laugh at me for, and I manage to get the full path name of the first file in the directory. 
I then assign that path name to `entry_file` pointer, where it gets opened by `fgets()`.
I believe `fgets()` should read each line individually until it sees a EOF character

Now, I had this section working before I added the directory stuff, where I was just opening one file by using `fopen()` with its full path name, and I haven't touched it. So I don't think my problem is here, but nothing is being printed to `fp1` at all, so I really don't know.

I then do some simple string comparisons and try to print matches to `fp1`
When it reaches the end of the file, it should close the file, and then go back up to `readdir()` and repeat the process with the next file

Thank you so much for any help. I probably sound like an idiot, but I just have no idea what could cause this.

Yes, I realize its very messy, and I have many unused and pointless variables. I've been trying to figure this out for days, trying many different methods.

```
int main(void)
{

char str1[10000];
char str2[] = { "Measure L1 current Tank Heater ON: Passed" };
char str3[] = { "Measure L1 current Tank Heater ON: Failed" };
char str4[] = { "Measure L1 current Manifold Heater ON: Passed" };
char str5[] = { "Measure L1 current Manifold Heater ON: Failed" };
char str6[] = { "Measure L1 current (verify heaters off) Manifold: Passed" };
char str7[] = { "Measure L1 current (verify heaters off) Manifold: Failed" };
char sn[] = { "Serial Number:                1" };
DIR* FD;
struct dirent* in_file;
int lcount = 0;//line counter
char *ret;
int linenum = 0;//temp line count
char mes[500];//measurement
double val = 0;//value
char unit[500];//units
char pathstr1[38] = ("C:/Users/liam.king/Desktop/TestFiles/");
char pathstr2[200];


DWORD retval = 0;

char buffer[BUFSIZE] = ("");
char buf[BUFSIZE] = ("");
char** lppPart = {NULL};

FILE *fp, *fp1, *filewrite;
FILE *entry_file;
//fp = fopen("C:/Users/liam.king/Desktop/TestFiles/ProBlueUnit_UpgradeRev4_Report[1022230.SA15E14082][9 39 00 AM][5 19 2015].txt", "r");
fp1 = fopen("C:/Users/liam.king/Desktop/ProBlueTestWrite.txt", "a");
filewrite = fopen("C:/Users/liam.king/Desktop/FileWrite.txt", "w+");
if (fp1 == NULL){
    printf("Invalid file name");
    return 0;
}

if ((FD = opendir(LONG_DIR_NAME))==NULL)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to open directory\n");


    return 0;
}
else{
    printf("Directory opened successful\n");
}
while ((in_file = readdir(FD))!= NULL){

    if (strcmp(in_file->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(in_file->d_name, "..") == 0)
        continue;


    fprintf(filewrite, "%s", pathstr1);
    fprintf(filewrite,"%s", in_file->d_name);
    fclose(filewrite);

    filewrite = fopen("C:/Users/liam.king/Desktop/FileWrite.txt", "r");



        fscanf(filewrite, "%[^\n]%*c", pathstr2);
        printf("%s\n", pathstr2);//check file name is correct

        entry_file = fopen(pathstr2, "r");
        fclose(filewrite);


        if (entry_file != NULL){
            //printf("SUCCESSFULL OPENING\n");
            //fprintf(fp1, "Does this work?\n");


        }
        else if (entry_file == NULL){
            printf("Error: Failed to open entry file\n");
            return 0;

        }

            while (fgets(buffer, 256, entry_file) != NULL){//string being stored in str1 from file *entry_file

lcount++;
                ret = strstr(str1, sn);
                if (ret != NULL){
                    fprintf(fp1, "%s\n", str1);
                }
                ret = strstr(str1, str2);
                if (ret != NULL){// compares str1 and 2
                    fprintf(fp1, "Found"" %s ""at line %d\n", str1, lcount);//if same, declare match and what line found at. 
                    linenum = lcount;
                }
//comparing more strings

            }
            fclose(entry_file);

    }

fclose(fp1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks incomplete.  Neither while loop is closed, nor the last if.  Also, it would be helpful to clean up the indentation for consistency -- it's a lot easier to read when it's right.

Comment: After the check for `entry_file != NULL`, there is no need for the check `entry_file == NULL` due to the `else`.

Comment: It is *significantly* incomplete. According to this you're writing to `filewrite` before it is opened, then opening it, reading from it, closing it, and repeating on the next iteration. The entire thing could use a full wash of checking your IO function calls rather than assuming they worked.  Via [The 10 Commandments](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) of C programming, #6 is easily the most frequently ignored.

Comment: Are you **really** using a file to concatenate 2 strings?

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, i realize it's inefficient, but it works. that's not what i have questions about.

Comment: You shouldn't be professionally programming in `C` if you do not understand the basics of pointers, arrays, strings, etc.  We don't *laugh* at newbie programmers, but you need to improve your skills with a good tutorial.  Read my answer for the reason you don't get any output.

Answer (score 0):

Since `pathstr2` is declared as a local array, you should use this:

```
while ((in_file = readdir(FD)) != NULL) {
    if (!strcmp(in_file->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(in_file->d_name, ".."))
        continue;

    snprintf(pathstr2, sizeof(pathstr2), "%s%s", pathstr1, in_file->d_name);
    entry_file = fopen(pathstr2, "r");
    ...
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), entry_file) != NULL) {
        lcount++;
        if (strstr(buffer, sn)) {
            fprintf(fp1, "%s", buffer);
        }
        if (strstr(buffer, str1)) {
            fprintf(fp1, "Found \"%s\" at line %d\n", str1, lcount);
            linenum = lcount;
        }
        ...
    }
    fclose(entry_file);
}
```

The tests you perform with `strstr` on the lines read from `entry_file` are not incorrect.  You should specify `buffer` instead of `str1` as the first argument.

Also note that `strstr` searches for the second string in the whole line.  If the string should be starting at the beginning of the line, you should write:

```
if (!strncmp(buffer, str1, strlen(str1))) {
    // line starts with str1
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it now traverses through the directory and prints every file path in the folder, but still doesn't print to my file. So i guess it's not working through the `fgets` and reading strings in the files correctly?

Comment: Might not the `readdir(FD)` get to "FileWrite.txt" (the output file) before the end of the directory, fail to open as it is being used, exit  `while ((in_file` loop and not read the rest of the directory?